# Error when connecting to Google Mail over SMTP using smtplib in Python

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

My issue is that when I run the following code, I get a WinError 10061, and from all of my searching it looks like this is a result of the foreign machine not being set up properly, but I assume that Google has that taken care of for gmail, so the error lies on my side.  All of the other examples I could find were using localhost and getting this error, and it was because they did not have a local mail server set up.  Would that still be the case with this problem?  I am sure  I am missing something obvious. Also, the error code is in full.  Thank you in advance!

```
import smtplib

fromaddr = 'email@email.com'
toaddrs  = 'otheremail@email.com'
msg = 'Random stuff!'


username = 'username'
password = 'pass'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Brett/PycharmProjects/Texting/sendMessage.py", line 13, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 238, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 317, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 288, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 424, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 415, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: Have you tried port 25?

Comment: @nikola for gmail?  Yes, I still got the same error though.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only say it works for me over here. Could it be a temporary failure or a networking problem (firewall, proxy, etc?)

Comment: Okay, so I tried it on another machine and it worked.  Don't know what was wrong with the first one.  Thanks all!

Comment: @RoyalBam & Clemens Klien-Robbenhaar - Yes, corporate firewalls seem to be one of the reasons behind this error. For testing, try similar code on different network and it may work. This was the case for me. So, I switch to using windows gui libraries (i.e. pywinauto, win32gui, pywin32, win32com).

Answer (score 0):

Having used the Gmail SMTP server in the past, I can only point out that the number for the SMTP port actually defaults to the appropriate one for Gmail, so the port argument (which can also be tacked onto the server name with a colon) can be omitted. Given this, you probably should try a different machine to ensure you're not running into networking errors, etc. Also, port 587 requires that ID check takes place, which means Gmail may think you're spamming or some other nonsense. Port 25, the default taken when no port number is entered, does not perform such a check.